# How can I invite other private users to a private Trello Board?

Tags: trello

I've setup a private Trello board and wish to invite some private users to it.

But when i click on invite it asks me to setup a team (see screenshot below)

[image: screenshot of Trello invite button]

My understanding is Teams are a paid feature of a Business plan. I only want to add private users to a private board so don't need a Business Plan.

How can I invite other private users to a private Trello Board

Answer (score 0):

A team is a group of boards and people. Use it to organize your list of people you want to interact with on these boards.

Business Teams is an add on.

What happens when you create a team?